# How to unit test statetransition in angular?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angular-ui-router, karma-jasmine

I am getting my head around unit test with karma. I want to check the state transitions so I created this test. The app starts off with going to the `landing` state and from there I want to go to `main`. This is a secure route so gets redirected to `login`:

```
it('should go to loginpage  before main', function () {
    $scope.$apply();
    expect($state.current.name).toBe('landing');    
    $state.transitionTo('main');
    $scope.$apply();
    expect($state.current.name).toBe('login');
});
```

In my app.js I have:

```
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event,next) {
        console.log('statechange from:', $state.current.name)
        //console.log('statechange to:',$state)

        if (!next.authenticate) {
            return;
        }

        //if next state is secure then check whether user is logged in:

        if (next.authenticate) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $state.transitionTo('login');
            console.log('goto login');
        }


    });
```

When I run my test with karma I get:

```
Chrome 51.0.2704 (Mac OS X 10.11.4) secure tests should go to loginpage  before main FAILED
    Expected '' to be 'landing'.
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dimitri/karma/basic_karma/appSpec.js:23:37)
    Expected '' to be 'login'.
```

Why is the `$state.current.name` empty?

github ref:https://github.com/dimitri-a/basic_karma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if you're trying to test two different things. First of all, you are testing if the `$stateChangeStart`-event gets fired. Secondly, you're testing your custom handler and logic inside it if it redirects when needed.

Unit testing is about testing a small part of your application. The `$stateChangeStart`-event is not part of your application, because it's part of the ui-router component. Testing if this event fires is not your responsibility. Even better; ui-router made their own test cases which checks if `$stateChangeStart` gets fired. You can see them yourself [right here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/a65c58f9edabff1e1097afe0da4b7c06868f32e2/test/ng1/stateEventsSpec.js#L73). You can be fairly certain the event gets triggered when it's needed.

So, how do we test your own custom logic? First, we need to refactor the `$rootScope.$on` handler.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', handleStateChange);

function handleStateChange(event, next) {
    console.log('statechange from:', $state.current.name)
    //console.log('statechange to:',$state)

    if (!next.authenticate) {
        return;
    }

    //if next state is secure then check whether user is logged in:

    if (next.authenticate) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.transitionTo('login');
        console.log('goto login');
    }
}
```

This way, we decouple you custom logic from the Angular `$rootScope` and we can test the logic by itself. Don't worry, your logic will still run when a state is about to change.

Next up the test itself. We don't have to deal with `$state.transitionTo` because we are not testing that part of the application (again, ui-router has it's own tests for `$state.transitionTo`). We don't even need to use `$scope.$apply`.

```
describe('handleStateChange()', function() {

    var $state;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$state_) {
        $state          = _$state_;

        // we spy on the $state.transitionTo method, to check if it 
        // has been called by our test case.
        spyOn($state, 'transitionTo');
    }));

    it('should transition to login state when authenticate:true', function () {
        // arrange
        var next = {
            name: 'main',
            authenticate: true
        };

        // act
        handleStateChange({}, next);

        // assert
        // in case of authenticate: true, $state.transitionTo should 
        // have been called with the 'login' name
        expect($state.transitionTo).toHaveBeenCalledWith('login');
    });

    it('should not transition to login state when authenticate:false', function () {
        // arrange
        var next = {
            name: 'landing',
            authenticate: false
        };

        // act
        handleStateChange({}, next);

        // assert
        expect($state.transitionTo).not.toHaveBeenCalledWith('login');
    });

});
```